Looking for name of a 2010-ish comedy featuring skydiving at a bachelor party.
I am trying to find the name of a movie that I saw a few years back, probably 2010 - 2012 on hbo, showtime or starz.  I can only remember bits of information, hoping someone here can recognize it and give me the title.
It was a bachelor party where they rented a plane to go skydiving, then the pilot pretended the plane was crashing, and everyone but the pilot jumped out and landed somewhere in Mexico.
They were then greeted by a drug lord who invited them up to his house for a party.
They did something to upset the drug lord so they took off.
There was a scene where one of the guys went into a church and stole/drank some wine.
There was a bullfighter that I think was scared of bullfighting, so the guys got a motorcycle, pretending the motorcycle was a bull, practiced with the bullfighter. 
At the end of the movie, the whole thing was a setup by one of the guys fiancee, and everyone was hired to play a part, I think it was to make sure he was committed to marrying her... can't really remember.
Movie was a comedy.

Ready Or Not from 2009 that had a suspiciously similar premise to The Hangover, also from 2009.

Four college buddies find themselves on the adventure of their lives, when on the morning after a Las Vegas bachelor party, they end up stranded deep in Mexico penniless, being chased, falling in love, and fighting to make it back across the border in time for the wedding.

They get there by skydiving and train a matador with a motorcycle. Both scenes are in the trailer:



For yet another movie with a similar plot, only done darker, see Mexican Sunrise from 2007.
